# Which IP addresses have aws ec2 instances been assigned, and how can they be searched quickly?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I'm using Cloudquery with PostgreSQL as datastore, but the data is JSON-coded, so I created a query to do the job.

```sql
with aws_account_config as (
  select '111111111111' as account_id, 'account_role_1' as account_name, 1 as account_order union
  select '222222222222' as account_id, 'account_role_2' as account_name, 2 as account_order union
  select '333333333333' as account_id, 'account_role_3' as account_name, 3 as account_order
),
instances_src as (
  select
    ec2i.*,
    i->>'NetworkInterfaceId' as NetworkInterfaceId,
    i->>'PrivateIpAddress' as PrivateIpAddressMain,
    pips->'PrivateIpAddress' as PrivateIpAddress
  from aws_ec2_instances ec2i,
  LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(network_interfaces) as i
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(
    case when jsonb_typeof(i->'PrivateIpAddresses') <> 'array'
    then null
    else i->'PrivateIpAddresses'
    end
  )  as pips on true
)

select
  aac.account_name, isrc.instance_id, isrc.NetworkInterfaceId, isrc.PrivateIpAddressMain, isrc.PrivateIpAddress
from instances_src isrc
left join aws_account_config aac on aac.account_id = isrc.account_id
order by aac.account_order, isrc.instance_id
```

Comment: what postgres has to do ? do you need to store ec2 instances specific data on the DB or store it ? it can be done by AWS CLI or PS tools.

Comment: I have a historical database containing all the assets we have deployed (and we are using Cloudquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) for your query, so, instead of propagating the info via query every time you need this info, the info is updated in the view during CloudQuery sync.